# Find the matrix of $T$ given :$ T([3, 5]) = [2, -1]$ and $T([1, 2]) = [3, 7]$ , $T$ is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

I know that T(**v**) = v' = **Av** , where **v** is the vector, v' is the image, and A is the matrix of transformation

So I've set the two images (v') equal to the matrix [S sub1, S sub 2]

What does [S sub1, S sub2] have to equal to?

I am stuck at this point and I don't know how to further attack this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to figure out what $T$ does to the two unit vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  The first column of $A$ is the vector $T(1,0)$.  The second column of $A$ is the vector $T(0,1)$.  Notice that $3(1,2)-(3,5)=(0,1)$.  So,
$$
T(0,1)=3T(1,2)-T(3,5)=3(3,7)-(2,-1)=(7,22).
$$
Thus, the second column of $A$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 7\\22\end{pmatrix}$.  Do the same for the first column with $(1,0)$.

Comment: -"Notice that 3(1,2)−(3,5)=(0,1)" How did you know which vectors to subrtract from which? By the way, your work checks out with the solution.

Comment: I wanted a $0$ in the first coordinate.  So, I saw that $3(1,2)$ would be $(3,6)$.  Then I could subtract $(3,5)$.  If the second coordinate had not been a $1$, I could then multiply by a constant.

Comment: I tried (3, 5) - 2(1, 2) = (1,1) but it doesn't equal to the (1,0) as for the first column.

Comment: @user114027 Try to make the second coordinate $0$.  Think about least common multiples.

Comment: Oh boy did I miss that. I was finally able to solve it using your way too using the 2T(3,5) - 5T(1,2). Thank you.

Comment: @user114027 That will do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is
$$ A . \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 3 & 1 \\ 5 & 2 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 2 & 3 \\ -1 & 7 \end{array} \right]  $$
Now can you finish?

Comment: How would you apply the transformations in here?

Comment: product of matrices

Comment: would this mean that Ax=B and A would be B times the inverse of x?

Comment: yes that's it....

Comment: The first column of A is (-11, -37) and the second one is (7, 22). Thanks buddy.